# File.Exist(...) method returns false

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, app-config, skinning

I'm currently working on this .Net/WPF project.

I'm trying to get the method to check to see if a skin file exists before applying. I have feeling that my address formatting my be wrong... Any ideas?

```
Dim lobjSPEConfigService As SPEConfigurationService = New SPEConfigurationService
Dim lobjSkinFilePath As String = CStr(lobjSPEConfigService.GetApplicationSetting("SkinFileLocation", GetType(String)))

If String.IsNullOrEmpty(lobjSkinFilePath) Then
    lobjSkinFilePath = "/SPE.Infrastructure.UI/Application/Resources/Skins/LightSkin"
Else
    Dim lblnFileExist = File.Exists(lobjSkinFilePath)
    If lblnFileExist = False Then
        lobjSkinFilePath = "/SPE.Infrastructure/SPE.Infrastructure.UI/Application/Resources/Skins/LightSkin"
    End If
End If
```

The file is being referenced thourg the project...

Comment: Have you tried the Pack URI? [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your file name and path correct (not sure I do not see your project) then the only thing I see missing is the file extension. I'm assuming it's .xaml

If you're loading anything as a resource you have to use WPF Pack URI's.

Some examples:

#### Absolute Path

```
"pack://application:,,,/ResourceFile.xaml"
"pack://application:,,,/ReferencedAssembly;component/ResourceFile.xaml"
```

#### Relative Path

```
"/ResourceFile.xaml"
"/ReferencedAssembly;component/ResourceFile.xaml"
```

Also get rid of your first else statement...you're not doing anything once you change the filename if its empty.

Comment: That was not the problem , but thank you for highlighting it,

Answer (score 1):

`File.Exists()` searches on disk. If it returns False the file doesn't exist on disk.

Where File.Exists is looking depends on  `CStr(lobjSPEConfigService.GetApplicationSetting("SkinFileLocation", GetType(String)))`

Check the value in the config file.

Make sure that path does exist and the application has sufficient rights to access/find it.

**EDIT**

To find an internal (assemly) resource [use the ResourceManager](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/6e2cb620-14c5-4996-9864-d43e6de5d665/)

Comment: What if you need to check to see a file exist whithin the application ??

Comment: @AshShafiee - In that case you should try to use it or query for it using the ResourceManager: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/6e2cb620-14c5-4996-9864-d43e6de5d665/